# Grouping by Aggregate Functions in #Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, group-by

I'm trying to find out which occupation has the max mean salary.
I've tried
`df.groupby('Occupation').agg({'Salary':'mean'})`

I think I've figured out how to get the max mean salary
but I can't figure out how to get the specific occupation title.
Any tips ? Thank you!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you perform a `groupby`, the features you use in your groupby become the index. Since the result of your groupby will be a Series (as you are only aggregating mean salary), you can use `idxmax` to then retrieve the index where the max salary occurs. However, if there are multiple occupations that share the same max salary, this will only return one of those occupations.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Occupation':list('aaabbbccc'),'Salary':[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]})
occupation_max_salary = df.groupby('Occupation').agg({'Salary':'mean'}).idxmax()[0]
```

`occupation_max_salary` is `'c'` as expected.

So if you need to account for possible ties in mean salary, then you can try the following:

```
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'Occupation':list('aaabbbccc'),'Salary':[1,2,3,7,8,9,7,8,9]})
salaries = df.groupby('Occupation').agg({'Salary':'mean'})
occupation_max_salary = salaries[salaries == salaries.max()].dropna().index.tolist()
```

In this case, `occupation_max_salary` is `['b','c']`